# Syncing multiple Socket.io clients

Tags: javascript, websocket, redis, socket.io, synchronization

I'm building an app that uses Angular.js for the front and Socket.IO & Redis on Express on the back.

The base usage of sockets is to allow one type of users to push items to lists that are consumed by groups of a second type of users.

A simple example:
Students can push messages into a class list and only teachers of this class can see the list.

I'm trying to sync the list between multiple teachers that are connected at different times,
the lists are stored in a Redis store and I'm wondering if the correct approach to sync clients:

A. Send the list on each update - saving the need of having to manage sync in the client and having potential missmatches.

B. Send the list only on connection and apply incremental updates on successive events.

I'm sure this has been addressed in the past as it seems quite a basic issue with socket communication but I was not able to find a definitive answer.

Thanks!

Comment: for single-server scale like you describe, go with whatever you feel best supporting. for larger scale, you probably must go with something more like B. what you describe sounds plenty plausible either way.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis! I guess I'll go for the more future-proof approach.

Comment: you can do it naive and just append each new message to the user's list if they are in the right "pool/room/list". to provide robustness to that simplicity, send a total expected length with each update and if a particular client is missing something, reload the whole list for that user alone (likely much the same as the client boot sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is not particularly large, then I'd think you want to go with something simple.  The simplest thing I can think of is as follows:

1. Student creates change to the list and sends message to the server (which could be an ajax call, doesn't have to be a web socket).
2. Server receives message and puts it into the appropriate list storage.
3. Server then looks for any clients monitoring that list and sends an update message to them.
4. Teacher connects to the server.  Any lists that the teacher is monitoring are sent in their entirety to the teacher and they are subscribed to updates for those lists.

This way, you're never actually doing sync which simplifies matters a lot - you're just doing download list and then incremental updates.  There's only one master store.  If a client goes off-line, they just get a fresh copy of the list and resubscribe to updates when they come back on-line.  Avoiding sync makes the whole solution a lot simpler.  This assumes the data is not particularly large so it's feasible to just get a fresh copy of the list as needed.

If you do want to do sync, then a fairly straightforward technique is to maintain one master copy of the store on the server and have every change transaction coin a monotonically increasing transaction ID.  Then, each synced copy can just keep track of the last transaction ID that they synced and request all transactions since then.  The data store needs to keep track of all changes as transactions (often by writing to a transaction log for each transaction or perhaps a feature in some databases) so any given set of transactions can be played back for any client that is syncing.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I might have misused the term sync in this context but your first suggestion seems like the way to go. While there might be a very large number of lists, each lists is very small so this would work.